# How to pack customized UIAlertController in one class (swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

My iOS app requires a customized group of alerts with similar functionality. Can I pack those in a class, so I don't have to copy paste in every UIViewController?

```
func displayAlert(msg:String, handler: (UIAlertAction) -> Void）{...} 
func successMsg (msg: String){...}  
func failMsg(msg: String){...}
```

I was trying to pack them into a subclass(AlertViewController) of UIViewController, but then there was runtime error:"Attempt to present <...UIAlertController...> on <...UIAlertController...> whose view is not in the window hierachy!"

code in myViewController:

```
@IBAction func leave() {
    let date = getDate()
    let datePresent = dateForPresent()
    if stID == nil || name == nil {
        return
    } else {
        alert.displayAlert("\(datePresent)"){action in
            self.request.getResult(self.request.leavePara(self.stID!, date: date, name: self.name!) ){ (result) in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    let flag = result["result","out_Flag"].int
                    print(result)
                    let msg = result["result","out_nszRtn"].string!
                    if flag == 0 {
                        self.alert.successMsg(msg){ action in
                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("personUnwind", sender: self)
                        }
                    }else {
                        self.alert.failMsg(msg)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So show the code that elicited that warning!

Comment: Not actually care how to fix the warnning, just asking what is the standard way to do such a thing.

Answer (score 6):

Please use this code.

```
func displayAlertWithMessage(title: String, message: string){
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStype: .Alert)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
    let rootVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
    rootVC?.presentViewController(ac, animated: true){}
}
```

If you want to display alert for specific view controller you can use this function.

```
func displayAlertWithMessage(viewController: UIViewController, title: String, message: string){
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStype: .Alert)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
    viewController.presentViewController(ac, animated: true){}
}
```

And you can call it function with this code.

```
displayAlertWithMessage(self, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This is close to what I want, but I was hoping for it present on an specific UIViewController(the one which is on screen right now) instead of the rootViewController. How do I do that? The code seems to display ALert message on the initial VC of my app no matter who's calling it.

Comment: @FateRiddle Hi, I've edit my answer.

Comment: It works, thanks man! By curiosity, what does `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController` call?

Comment: So what I do is creating a class `AlertUIViewController` where I write the above function `displayAlertWithMessage`, then in MyViewController: `let alert = AlertUIViewController()` then call function`alert.displayAlertWithMessage(...)`, is it OK to code this way? I'm concerned about creating an VC class without actual view, and also curious what you would do it in a better way? Thanks again, big help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the error you were getting was about, but if you want to avoid a subclass you could implement a `UIAlertViewController` initializer that returns an object customized to your needs.

For example, the following could be written at a global level:

```
extension UIAlertController {

    enum AlertMessageID {
        case SaveFailed
    }

    convenience init(messageID: AlertMessageID) {
        switch messageID {
            case .SaveFailed:
                self.init(title: "Oops", message: "The save failed.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        }
        let okayButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        self.addAction(okayButton)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great way to solve the problem. A dumb question, where should I write this code?

Comment: This code could be written anywhere, it just needs written at a global level. But you can put it in any Swift file.